# FailedToLoadPlugin python_3000_backticks when running flake8 after upgrading flake8 to v6.0.0

Tags: python, flake8, pycodestyle

After upgrading from flake8==5.0.4 to flake8==6.0.0 and pycodestyle==2.9.1 to pycodestyle==2.10, running flake8 in my project is broken, (and not because a of -documented- breaking change in this libraries).

The particular error I'm facing is in pycodestyles, who cannot load the python_3000_backticks plugin (whatever that means), but I'm running into this when running flake8, so I'm hesitant on who to blame for this.

Has anyone else encountered this issue after upgrading flake8? Is there some known workaround?

Comment: you've forced an incompatible set of versions -- pip should have warned you

Comment: @anthonysottile shouldn't flake8==6.0.0 and pycodestyles==2.10 be compatible? They are the latest release of each. Or do you think the incompatibility is being caused by a third module? Don't know if its important, but I'm using poetry==1.2 as a dependency resolutor and it did not warn about any conflict.

Comment: if it's trying to import `python_3000_backticks` then you have flake8<6

Comment: Did you fix this? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: @anthonysottile don't think so...

Comment: @trevor I downgraded to flake8<6.0.0, didn't find a way to make it work with newest flake8

Comment: @NicolasMartinez I maintain flake8, that import is only present in the 5.x version.

Comment: @anthonysottile - I use ArchLinux and have the flake8 version 6.0.0-1 installed. I receive the same import error error as Nicholas. I just verified my flake8 version with `sudo pacman -Q --info flake8`.

Comment: This was a user error on my part. I had flake8 installed with pip in `.local/bin`. Once I removed that with `pip uninstall flake8` the OS packaged version in `/usr/bin/flake8` was used.

Comment: @trevor you might want to post that as an answer